# iOS - Implementing a Class for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UIView`, with lots of `UITexfields`,

```
UITextField *field1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 292, 50, 20)];
field1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
field1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
field1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
field1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
field1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:inputFont size:fontSize];
field1.placeholder = @"size";
[self addSubview:field1];
```

Can I create a `UITextField` Class and create an instance of this class with these parameters preset? -so as to reduce the code: (If I have lots of fields the code gets very long and repetitive? -

Can i get some help on how about to set up this class! -thank you

Comment: If you need to add a method to an existing class, perhaps to add functionality to make it easier to do something in your own application, the easiest way is to use a category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes You Can do this by making a `BaseUITextFeild` `.h` and `.m` file as shown in the following image.
[image]

[image]

And then Just add the following code regarding your design in `BaseUITextFeild.m` file

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [self setupUI];
    [self setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
}

// Function to setup the common UI throught the app.
- (void)setupUI {
    [self setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/225.0 green:120.0/225.0 blue:120.0/225.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    [self setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
}
```

**Generating a custom UITextField programmatically**
And then just `import "BaseUITextFeild.h"` in the `ViewController` Where you want to use it.

```
BaseUITextFeild *field1 = [[BaseUITextFeild alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 292, 50, 20)];
[self addSubview:field1];
```

**Generating a custom UITextField From Interface Builder(Storyboard/.XIB)**
Add a UITextfield and then just Change the Class to your Custom TextView Class.
[image]

By Applying Following technique you can use this same `UITextFeild` through out the Application, Just need to `import BaseUITextFeild.h`.

**You can also use this UITextFieldCategory**

Follow this Two Example [UITextField+withFrame.h](https://gist.github.com/adeel/1112262) and [UITextField+ColoredPlaceholder.h](https://gist.github.com/digidigo/776532).
You can also customize you `UITextField` as per your need.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, it works only when you use interface builder generated, you have to edit your class in such a way so you can initialize either through programmatic defined UI or xib based interface.

Comment: Subclasssing is unnecessary for this. Just create a method that returns what you want.

Comment: @sosborn what if I want to use Custom `UITextFeild` throughout my application.

Comment: Then make a category of uitextfield that has your method.

Comment: This seems perfect, and it works for me ! but Would somebody please clear up the comments discussion above, because it adds to my confusion : so do i need to use interface builder / story board / xib to use this method ?

Comment: @TaskinulHaque Have a look at updated answer I have added UITextField Category Example.

Comment: @TaskinulHaque I have Updated answer regarding "How To add a custom TextField from Interface Builder."

Comment: Ok i've been trying this  . ..  and I just can't get it to work . .  certain things like setting Context Alignment or changing font size won't work :/  . . ..  also the issue I'm having is I'm not displaying these textfields in a UIViewController much rather a UIView could that be a problem ? - Parsers answer below works  . . . but the problem for instance with his answer is how would i Set a Font ? (as a global variable?)

Answer (score 2):

Create a method

```
-(UITextField*)createTextFieldWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
    textField.placeholder = @"size";
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    return textField;
}
```

for creating multiple textfields call this method

```
UITextField *text1 = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UITextField *text2 = [self createTextFieldWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview:textField] textfield shouldn't be added to self.view in helper methods as you are imposing restriction by making it to work only on self.view, what if user wants to add it to some other views.

Comment: in that case you can make the view as argument in the method.

Comment: using this approach  . . . how would you change the position of each textField?

Comment: in this method you have to pass the frame for setting the Frame/position

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `xib` with the `UITextField` created as you want and reuse that every time you need.

Or you can subclass `UITextField` and do the additional setup inside.

Comment: He wants to reduce the code, so this will help him, the only thing that he'll need to do is to place the `textField.text` value .

Comment: what if he is not using story board and xib's